# Cleaning up a messy data file to a more readable format in Python?

Tags: python, file-io

I have a text file (heavily modified for this example) which has some data that I want to extract and do some calculations with it. However the text file is extremely messy, so I'm trying to clean it up and write it out to new files first.

Here is the .txt file I'm working with: http://textuploader.com/5elql

I am trying to extract the data which is under the titles (called “Important title”). The only possible way to do that is to first locate a string which always occurs in the file, and its called “DATASET” because all the mess above and below the important data will cover an arbitrary number of lines, difficult to remove manually. Once that’s done I want to store the data in separate files so that it is easier to analyse like this:

http://textuploader.com/5elqw

The file names will be concatenated with the title + the date.

Here is what I have tried so far

```
with open("example.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.startswith('DATASET:'):
            fileTitle = line[9:]
        if line.startswith("DATE:"):
            fileDate = line[:]
            print(fileTitle+fileDate)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
IMPORTANT TITLE 1
DATE: 12/30/2015

IMPORTANT TITLE 2
DATE: 01/03/2016
```

So it appears my loop manages to locate the lines where the titles inside the file are and print them out. But this is where I run out of steam. I have no idea on how to extract the data under those titles from there onwards. I have tried using file.readlines() but it outputs all the mess that is in between Important Title 1 and Important Title 2.

Any advice on how I can read all the data under the titles and output them into separate files? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you're reading the file in by line instead of the whole thing?

Comment: Are there ALWAYS 10 *data points* in a dataset??  And can you be sure that the format, i.e. tabs, spaces, empty lines, is consistent? Do the *garbage* sections always start with a ```%```?

Comment: @patrick one should always try to process files lazily (line by line) to make the code load-proof.

Comment: @wwii No I modified this text file to present a simpler version. The data set can have hundreds if not thousands of x, y data. But that is irrelavant because I simply want to clean up all the garbage sections and present the data more cleanly in new output files so I can use loadtxt or csvreader later on to do calculations.

Comment: What about the blank lines before and after the *garbage*?? are they consistent?

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex.

```
import re

pattern = r"(\s+X\s+Y\s*)|(\s*\d+\s+\d+\s*)"
prog = re.compile(pattern)

with open("example.txt") as file:
cur_filename = ''
content = ""
for line in file:
    if line.startswith('DATASET:'):
        fileTitle = line[9:]
    elif line.startswith("DATE:"):
        fileDate = line[6:]
        cur_filename = (fileTitle.strip() + fileDate.strip()).replace('/', '-')
        print(cur_filename)
        content_title = fileTitle + line
    elif prog.match(line):
        content += line
    elif cur_filename and content:
        with open(cur_filename, 'w') as fp:
            fp.write(content_title)
            fp.write(content)
        cur_filename = ''
        content = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how you want to store your data but assuming you want a dictionary you could use regex to check if the incoming line matched the pattern, then because `fileTitle` isn't global you could use that as the key and add the values. I also added `rstrip('\r\n')` to remove the newline characters after fileTitle.

```
import re

#if you don't want to store the X and Y, just use re.compile('\d\s+\d+')
p = re.compile('(\d\s+\d+)|(X\s+Y)')
data={}
with open("input.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.startswith('DATASET:'):
            fileTitle = line[9:].rstrip('\r\n')
        if line.startswith("DATE:"):
            fileDate = line[:]
            print(fileTitle+fileDate)
        if p.match(line):
            if fileTitle not in data:
                data[fileTitle]=[]
            line=line.rstrip('\r\n')
            data[fileTitle].append(line.split('\t'))
            if len(data[fileTitle][len(data[fileTitle])-1]) == 3:
                data[fileTitle][len(data[fileTitle])-1].pop()

print data
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another regex solution:

```
sep = '*************************\n'

pattern = r'DATASET[^%]*'
good_stuff = re.compile(pattern)
pattern = r'^DATASET: (.*?)$'
title = re.compile(pattern, flags = re.MULTILINE)
pattern = r'^DATE: (.*?)$'
date = re.compile(pattern, flags = re.MULTILINE)

with open(r'foo.txt') as f:
    data = f.read()
for match in good_stuff.finditer(data):
    data = match.group()
    important_title = title.search(data).group(1)
    important_date = date.search(data).group(1)
    important_date = important_date.replace(r'/', '-')
    fname = important_title + important_date + '.txt'
    print(sep, fname)
    print(data)
    ##with open(fname, 'w') as f:
    ##    f.write(data)
```